# C#, RabbitMq How can I send back the processed message

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I just started learning RabbitMQ yesterday and I don't understand how it can be implemented.

Here is my producer

```
public class RabbitMQProducerService: IMessageSender
    {
        public void SendMessage<T>(T message)
        {
            var factory = new ConnectionFactory { HostName = "localhost" };
            var connection = factory.CreateConnection();

            var channel = connection.CreateModel(); 
            channel.QueueDeclare("Input", exclusive: false);

            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message);
            var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
            channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "", routingKey: "Input", basicProperties: null, body: body);
        }
    }
```

And my subscriber

```
string exepction = "";
StatisticOfTest statistic;

var factory = new ConnectionFactory
{
    HostName = "localhost"
};
var connection = factory.CreateConnection();
using var channel = connection.CreateModel();
channel.QueueDeclare("Input", exclusive: false);

var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
consumer.Received += (model, eventArgs) =>
{
    SolutionService solution = new SolutionService();
    var body = eventArgs.Body.ToArray();
    var jsonStr = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
    SolutionAddModel solutionAdd = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SolutionAddModel>(jsonStr);
    
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(solution.Validating(solutionAdd)))
    {
        statistic = solution.Create(solutionAdd); //I want to return statistic
    }
    else
    {
        exepction = solution.Validating(solutionAdd); // Or Exception
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"Message received: {jsonStr}");
};
channel.BasicConsume(queue: "Input", autoAck: true, consumer: consumer);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Based on the result, I want to return statistic or exception. But to another queue, for example, to some Output queue

Comment: You can just publish a message inside `Received` event handler as you do it inside `SendMessage()` -> `channel.BasicPublish(...)` (the queue or exchange can be created in other place or inside consumer event).

Answer (score 0):

`consumer.Received += (model, eventArgs) => { ... }`

The `...` is the place when you declare what will happen, when a new message is received. The code there would be an event handler for a `Received` event.

In your case you want each new message to be published to a queue on some condition. Easy to do, just publish a message in your event handler code:

```
...
// Create a separate channel for sending messages to the output queue
var outputChannel = connection.CreateModel();

// Declare the output queue, you want to send messages to
outputChannel.QueueDeclare("Output", exclusive: false);

// Specify how the actual processing is going to happen
consumer.Received += (model, eventArgs) =>
{
    var body = GetMessageBody(eventArgs.Body); // This is where you get new message content based on the received message.

    outputChannel.BasicPublish(exchange: "", routingKey: "Input", basicProperties: null, body: body);
};
...
```

Also, looking at your producer code: you don't need to create a new connection, a new channel, and declare a queue *every* time you want to send a message. You could do it beforehand just once. It would really save RabbitMQ's resources.

RabbitMQ also has a connection limit, so sometime in the future your program would stop working. It is better if an application actually uses **a single** connection for everything, if possible, just spawning channels where needed.

Also, don;t forget, that IConnection and IModel are implementing IDisposable, so you should dispose of them properly.

This is how you should do it:

```
// 'using' tells the compiler to generate a Dispose call for this object at the end of the current block.
using var connection = connectionFactory.CreateConnection();
uisng var channel = connection.CreateModel();
channel.QueueDeclare("Input", exclusive: false);
for (var i = 0; i < 100l i++)
    producer.SendMessage(i);
```